# k8s go client: how to pass a v1.Deployment type to a function

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm new to go and playing with k8s go-client. I'd like to pass items from `deploymentsClient.List(metav1.ListOptions{})` to a funcion. `fmt.Printf("%T\n", deploy)` says it's type `v1.Deployment`. So I write a function that takes `(deploy *v1.Deployment)` and pass it `&deploy` where deploy is an item in the `deploymentsClient.List`. This errors with `cmd/list.go:136:38: undefined: v1` however. What am I doing wrong?

Here are my imports

```
import (
    //  "encoding/json"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    //yaml "github.com/ghodss/yaml"
    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
    // "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/api/errors"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)
```

Then I get the list of deployments:

```
    deploymentsClient := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(ns)
    deployments, err := deploymentsClient.List(metav1.ListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    for _, deploy := range deployments.Items {
        fmt.Println(deploy.ObjectMeta.SelfLink)
        //      printDeploymentSpecJson(deploy)
        //      printDeploymentSpecYaml(deploy)

    }
```

Comment: Where does `v1` come from? Did you import it?

Comment: You're not importing the module as v1.

Comment: If i change the type to `*metav1.Deployment` i get the error `cmd/list.go:141:38: undefined: "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1".Deployment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import "k8s.io/api/apps/v1", Deployment is defined in the package. See https://godoc.org/k8s.io/api/apps/v1.